# Select em três tabelas em uma lista - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

Tenho três tabelas:

```
ESCRITORIOS
id
nome

ESCRITORIOS_SEGMENTO
id_escritorio
id_segmento

SEGMENTOS
id
nome_segmento
```

O que preciso é dar um SELECT para listar essas informações assim

**SEGMENTO BLABLA:**

escriorio 1, escritorio 2

**SEGMENTO BLIBLI**

escriorio 1, escritorio 4

**SEGMENTO BLOBLO**

escriorio 2, escritorio 3

**SEGMENTO BLUBLU**

escritorio 3

Tentei de várias formas, com LEFT JOIN, GROUP, mas não rolou....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui!

```
SELECT *, associados.caminho AS caminho_associado, area.caminho AS caminho_area, area.id AS id_area FROM area LEFT JOIN associados_area ON associados_area.idarea = area.id LEFT JOIN associados ON associados.id = associados_area.idassociado WHERE associados.ativo = "1"    ORDER BY area.nome_pt ASC
```