# Mysql > query com colunas dinâmicas

Tags: mysql, query

Amigos tenho uma questão....
Possuo as seguintes tabelas no Mysql:

```
alunos (id, nome, etc)
turmas (id, turma, etc)
matricula (id, turmaID, alunoID)
disciplinas (id, turmaID)
avaliacoes (id, avaliacao)
notas (id, matriculaID, disciplinaID, avaliacaoID, nota)
```

Consigo realizar a query utilizando JOIN de forma satisfatória e retornando as informações corretamente.
As avaliações serão as mesmas para cada disciplina, contudo a quantidade de avaliações é variável. Sendo assim, as notas dos alunos são retornadas linha por linha.
Seria possível juntar numa Query as notas das avaliações do aluno na mesma linha?

```
EX: 
disciplina   aluno          Nota1   Nota2   Nota3
Matemática | joao manoel  | 10    | 8     | 9
```

Espero ter conseguido me expressar... Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos!

Comment: Uma das maneiras mais práticas é usar JOINs, uma pesquisada no site por JOIN e MYSQL pode ajudar. Imagino que tenha sido respondida já, se eu achar link posto aqui.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo bem parecido com o que você precisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114581/70

Comment: Aqui  tem um material legal para entender JOINs: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70

Comment: Quanto à formatação do resultado, para evitar mostrar colunas repetidas (o que é inevitável num join desse tipo), temos algumas postagens também, mas aí depende de especificar qual linguagem é usada para exibição

Comment: Prezado @Bacco, agradeço muito pela velocidade na resposta. Eu consigo fazer os JOINS satisfatoriamente entre as tabelas e retornar os valores de forma correta. Contudo, minha dúvida seria quanto a forma de exibição do resultado mesmo. Achei poderia haver uma outra forma de retornar os registros de forma mais _"mastigada"_ para o HTML.

Comment: Se está usando HTML, provavelmente está usando uma camada de ligação entre o MySQL e o HTML. É o caso de formatar nessa camada, seja PHP ou qq outra linguagem. Eu mesmo já respondi umas 2 perguntas no site sobre como evitar repetição de titulos, e a lógica é bem simples.

Comment: Agora, importante no seu caso, quando for assim, explicar tudo na pergunta, pois algum colega poderia ter perdido o maior tempão para te ajudar postando o JOIN, sendo que o problema é outro. Fica a sugestão de [edit] e descrever o problema de maneira mais completa, deixando bem clara a dificuldade (o que tentou, que código já tem, e o que saiu diferente do esperado), aí poderemos indicar uma resposta com a solução melhor, ou caso não haja, responder exatamente em cima da dúvida.

Comment: Ok. Pode deixar que seguirei seu conselho! Grato!